# OpenProject Installation

Tags: apache, centos, openproject

I need to Install open project in Centos but while installing facing an error given below. How this can be resolved?

```
[apache2] ./bin/preinstall
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 216.14.113.158
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 216.14.113.158
 * cpanel-plugins: 216.14.113.158
 * base: ftpmirror.your.org
 * epel: mirror.uic.edu
 * extras: ftpmirror.your.org
 * updates: ftpmirror.your.org
No package mod_ssl available.
Error: Nothing to do
```